# Auth0 login dialog with AuthenticationClient

Tags: auth0

I want to have a login dialog with Auth0 like this:

[image: Auth0]

How can I write a javascript code to have this dialog? Is it possible to write the code using AuthenticationClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to build a custom UI, you can use the [Auth0js](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9) library. There is an example [here](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11#more-examples) of the Auth0js (select the Custom UI tab). Auth0js is the SDK used for interacting with the [Auth0 Authentication API](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication). What kind of application are you building or have you built that you want to integrate Auth0 into?

I'd also suggest reading up on [Universal Login](https://auth0.com/docs/hosted-pages/login) and [Lock vs Custom UI](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/when-to-use-lock). Feel free to checkout https://community.auth0.com/ you may find some threads there helpful, others who have implemented similar systems or even have better luck getting your questions answered if they are Auth0 specific.

Cheers!